# strange border aroung text of img

Tags: html, css, image, panel

I have different images on my website, and some of them (PNG images) have a strange grey border around the text part of image, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJAJi.jpg

The text is inside the image, not separated.
The css/html code of the image is:

```css
#bor_panel {
 border-radius: 12px;
 border: 2px solid #287396;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 170px;
 height: 170px;
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="bor_panel">
  <img src="images/raro_page/Ampia_Connettivita_B.jpg" id="raro_panel_connettivita" alt="raro robot connettivita" /> 
</div>
```

Any idea? It seems a normal img tag...

------EDIT------

This is the original image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSdrF.jpg

It seems ok

Comment: Uh, maybe because the text is like that?

Comment: Seems like an issue in the file. How's it look in an image editor? Can you provide a link or upload the image?

Comment: I put the original image in the post. It seems ok

Comment: check the image well, this border is a part of the image but you cannot see it will as it on the edge ... and you put the image inside the container with papdding you can see it as there white around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in your image. I opened your [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6oSu.png) in the photoshop and found this after zooming the image. There is an gray space in your image around the text.

[image]

I have edited your image in photoshop and make a snippet below. Now there is no border.

```css
#bor_panel {
  border-radius: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #287396;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  display: flex;
}
img{
width:126px;
height: 126px;
margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="bor_panel">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdgFO.jpg" id="raro_panel_connettivita" alt="raro robot connettivita" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is strange. It is a part of the image you are using. Try using some image editing application to remove that border. It doesn't seem like its due to CSS or HTML

Comment: I put the original image in the post. It seems ok

Comment: can you share the code that you are actually using. maybe on jsfiddle or something similar

Comment: @lucacatr  
check the image well, this border is a part of the image but you cannot see it will as it on the edge ... and you put the image inside the container with papdding you can see it as there white around it